# Laravel undefined variable: search

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, undefined

Version of Laravel 5.0 and following is my code:

**My form:**

```
<form method="get" action="{{ url('result')}}" class="search-wrap" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control search" placeholder="Search" name="key"/>
        <button class="btn btn-primary submit-search text-center" type="submit">
            <i class="icon-search"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**My controller:**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\products;

public function searchName(Request $request){
    $key = $request->key;
    $data = product::where('name','like','%'.$key.'%')->get();
    return view('footwear/result',['search'=>$data]);
}
```

**My route:**

```
Route::get('result', 'myControler@searchName');
```

**My view:**

```
<?php
    var_dump($search);
?>
```

I receive the following error: (Undefined variable: search)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in your routes, why don't you
Try:

```
Route::post('result', 'myControler@searchName');
```

or

```
Route::any('result', 'myControler@searchName');
```

change method to post in form too, and try.

NOTE: I should have added this as comment but my rep is less than 50.

Comment: can i see your result.blade.php .

Comment: Oh, i only write  : <?php
   var_dump($search);
    ?>

Comment: Hic , I has a new prodblem , if i use method : POST, I can't used the pagination :(